# How can I force a reload on a previously require'd module?

Tags: neovim, lua

I have updated the module I'm writing, but:

```
:lua= require('XXX')
```

keeps returning a cached value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
lua package.loaded.XXX = nil
lua require("XXX")
```

More information on [What is a way to reload lua scripts during run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2812556)

Comment: That’s it - https://neovim.io/doc/user/luaref.html#package.loaded() - thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)